# can't change filenames with os.rename because [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

I have several filenames that are named like numbers like: 201810160820. I want to change the name to date + time, so the file will be renamed to: 16/10/2018 08:20.

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

os.chdir('/root/Desktop/calls')

for name in os.listdir('.'):
    newname = name[len(name)-6:len(name)-4]+'/'+name[len(name)-8:len(name)-6]+'/'+name[len(name)-12:len(name)-8]+' '+name[len(name)-4:len(name)-2]+':'+name[len(name)-2:len(name)]    
    os.rename(name, newname)
```

I gets an error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I write this code on python 2.7 with kali linux.
the files are existing and I can change the file name if I don't do a loop.
where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` returns just the names of the files, without the path names. You should use `os.path.join` to join the directory name with the file names in order for `os.rename` to locate them:

```
dir = '.'
for name in os.listdir(dir):
    newname = name[len(name)-6:len(name)-4]+'-'+name[len(name)-8:len(name)-6]+'-'+name[len(name)-12:len(name)-8]+' '+name[len(name)-4:len(name)-2]+'-'+name[len(name)-2:len(name)]    
    os.rename(os.path.join(dir, name), newname)
```

Note that file names cannot contain `'/'` or `':'`, so you should use something like `-` as a delimiter instead.

Comment: it worked! but why? In the original program I changed the working directory with os.chdir('/root/Desktop/calls').

Comment: The key point, as I've explained in the answer, is to join the directory name with the file names; otherwise `name` contains just a file name and `os.rename` would not be able to locate it.